# Adding subview then releasing it: "modifying view that is being finalized"

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiview

I've got a UIButton called tagButton and a UIScrollView called tagsView.

Inside my `-(void)renderTags` method, I do

```
[[self.tagsView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

...to clear the decks, then I walk through a pair of arrays called `allTags` and `activeTags`, alternately creating "lit" and "unlit" buttons for each tag the user has ever used in the app. So far so good. But when I add the newly created UIButton to my view, thusly:

```
[self.tagsView addSubview:tagButton];
[tagButton release];
```

...the first time, nothing happens on the view, the tag button doesn't show up. The second time I put that same string in (which fires `-toggleTag` rather than `-createTag`, but ends up in the same rendering method), I get the console message `modifying layer that is being finalized = 0x82b3ec0`.

If I comment out `[tagButton release]`, though, everything works. So, what gives? I thought adding a subview to a superview made the superview retain it. I'm not going to deal with this button again except to tell it to remove itself next time I render my tag list, so it seems like the view controller ought to release it.

Comment: where do u define tagButton? if u arent retaining it to begin with then no need to release it

Comment: and are you definitely sure that tagsView is not nil?

Comment: @Daniel. D'oh. That's it. I'm getting it with a `[UIButton buttonWith...]` convenience method so it's already autoreleased. Would you please say something about that as an Answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: answered...damn 15 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you arent retaining tagButton to begin with, therefore there is no need to release it...hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Three months into full-time iPhone development, I'm still not exempt from rookie mistakes...

Comment: three months isnt that long :)